# Opel Meriva 2009 - Clicking noise

Tags: acceleration

I have Opel Meriva 2009 model. It produces clicking noise while accelerating above 100km/hr. When I drive in lesser speed no noise. Also, no noise while accelerating in idle or braking. Could you please help on what could be the potential problem here.